# IntelliJ hides some of Maven's output

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ's maven run window hides critical sections of the output. For example, if I run compile and there is a compilation issue: in the "Run" window, next to it, there is something that looks like "console output" but don't be fooled, it's not the whole thing.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project MyScripts: Fatal error compiling
```

How do I now it's not the whole thing? I ran the same command from the command line and, low and behold:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project MyScripts: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 1.11 -> [Help 1]
```

That last part, "invalid target release 1.11" is absolutely critical for understanding what went wrong. Not knowing the whole error output leads to a lot of time waste. Is there a way to make IntelliJ not hide it?

Comment: Only `11` for JDK 11...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click on the root node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CkfZ.png) to see the complete Maven output.

Comment: It was that simple! I hope I'm not the only one that was this dumb. Or do I Haha

Answer (score -2):

For `maven-compiler-plugin` the valid JDK versions are: 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 10, 11, 12, 13 ...

I prefer use `11` instead of `1.11` like this

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source> 
        <target>11</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or a shorhand:
In this case you don't have to configure the compiler plugin.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: This was not the question, the question was how to see this error in IntelliJ IDEA.